# node.js - How to test my HTTPserver keep-alive connection

Tags: javascript, node.js

in an exercise we got in school I wrote a static HTTP server with node.js module net.
Now I would like to test the keep-alive HTTP requests using the HTTP module in node.js
My problem is that with every code like this:

```
for(var i=0; i<10 ; i++)
{
    var req = http.request(options, function(){console.log('awesome')});
    req.end();

}
```

I just get 10 different clients, but I would like to test the situation in which one client send 10 requests one after the other (at the moment he recieves a response he will send a new request, in less then 2 seconds).
So I tried doing this:

```
    var req = http.request(options, function(){console.log('awesome')});
    req.on('connection', function(req, res){
        console.log("in connection in clinet");
        // Coding for more requests...
    });
    req.end();
```

but it never seems to print "in connection in clinet".
Whats seems to be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: The event is [`response`, not `connection`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_response).

Comment: Yes you are right, but response event only emits once...

Comment: What do you expect it to do? Keep-alive is implemented in Node using agents, if that’s what you’re looking for; see the link.